# How to use jQuery UI Tabs on DotNetNuke 6.2+

Tags: jquery-ui, dotnetnuke-6

I'm using the latest version of DNN and Chris Hammond's VS 2010 template for module development.  I'm simply attempting to place a jQueryUI Tab control on my page.  I looked at the documentation and it seems like this should work.  When I view source I can see that jQueryUI is being included in the header.  I also tried replacing the tabs() call with dnnTabs(), but no difference.  So, what am I missing here?  Thanks in advance!

Code in module.js:

```
(function ($) {
    $("#tabz").tabs();
})(jQuery);
```

---

Code in MyModule.ascx.cs:

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Framework.jQuery.RequestRegistration();

    if (Framework.AJAX.IsInstalled()) {
        Framework.AJAX.RegisterScriptManager();
    }
}
```

---

Code in MyModule.ascx

```
 <dnn:DnnJsInclude ID="DnnJsInclude" runat="server" FilePath="~/DesktopModules/MyModule/module.js" />

<div id="tabz">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Page 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Page 2</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="tabs-1">
        This is tab 1.
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2">
        This is tab 2.
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I did manage to figure out how to use Telerik's RadTabStrip with RadMultiPage to accomplish the same task.

Answer (score 0):

Your over doing it, its much simpler than that.

In your .ascx page you should include:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $( "#tabz" ).tabs();
});
</script>
```

And you dont need anything in your code behind.

Source: http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/